# How to increase Camera Speed in Android with CameraX

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

Hi I am new to Android Programming.

As the title, How to increase speed of take picture with CameraX or Camera2 or OpenCV?
My project goal is image processing(4k image) with Android and OpenCV as fast as possible.

If you have any comments, please let me know.

```
void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                .build();

        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.v("Info", "Button Click");
                imageCapture.takePicture(executor , new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                        super.onCaptureSuccess(image);
                        Log.v("Info", "Capture Success = W:" + image.getWidth() + "/" + "H:" + image.getHeight());

                        Bitmap bitmap = toBitmap(image);
                        Log.v("Info", "Bitmat cvt = W:" + bitmap.getWidth() + "/" + "H:" + bitmap.getHeight());

                        Mat matOriginal = new Mat();
                        Mat matResult = new Mat();
                        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, matOriginal);
                        Log.v("Info", "Mat cvt = W:" + matOriginal.width() + "/" + "H:" + matOriginal.height());

                        Imgproc.cvtColor(matOriginal, matResult, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

                        image.close();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                        Log.v("Info", "Capture Error");
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is Logcat Message to measure Time

2021-05-12 16:20:40.427  V/Info: Button Click

2021-05-12 16:20:40.976  V/Info: Capture Success = W:3840/H:2160

2021-05-12 16:20:41.092  V/Info: Bitmap cvt = W:3840/H:2160

2021-05-12 16:20:41.106  V/Info: Mat cvt = W:3840/H:2160

as the Result

549msec - takePicture (too Slow, I think)

116msec - Bitmap Conversion

014msec - Mat Conversion

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want resolution image is high. you can use image analysis for high speed capture https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137672)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the image to Mat without converting first to bitmap,
Use this extension function:

```
fun Image.yuvToRgba(): Mat {
  val rgbaMat = Mat()

  if (format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
    && planes.size == 3) {

    val chromaPixelStride = planes[1].pixelStride

    if (chromaPixelStride == 2) { // Chroma channels are interleaved
        assert(planes[0].pixelStride == 1)
        assert(planes[2].pixelStride == 2)
        val yPlane = planes[0].buffer
        val uvPlane1 = planes[1].buffer
        val uvPlane2 = planes[2].buffer
        val yMat = Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1, yPlane)
        val uvMat1 = Mat(height / 2, width / 2, CvType.CV_8UC2, uvPlane1)
        val uvMat2 = Mat(height / 2, width / 2, CvType.CV_8UC2, uvPlane2)
        val addrDiff = uvMat2.dataAddr() - uvMat1.dataAddr()
        if (addrDiff > 0) {
            assert(addrDiff == 1L)
            Imgproc.cvtColorTwoPlane(yMat, uvMat1, rgbaMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12)
        } else {
            assert(addrDiff == -1L)
            Imgproc.cvtColorTwoPlane(yMat, uvMat2, rgbaMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21)
        }
    } else { // Chroma channels are not interleaved
        val yuvBytes = ByteArray(width * (height + height / 2))
        val yPlane = planes[0].buffer
        val uPlane = planes[1].buffer
        val vPlane = planes[2].buffer

        yPlane.get(yuvBytes, 0, width * height)

        val chromaRowStride = planes[1].rowStride
        val chromaRowPadding = chromaRowStride - width / 2

        var offset = width * height
        if (chromaRowPadding == 0) {
            // When the row stride of the chroma channels equals their width, we can copy
            // the entire channels in one go
            uPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width * height / 4)
            offset += width * height / 4
            vPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width * height / 4)
        } else {
            // When not equal, we need to copy the channels row by row
            for (i in 0 until height / 2) {
                uPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width / 2)
                offset += width / 2
                if (i < height / 2 - 1) {
                    uPlane.position(uPlane.position() + chromaRowPadding)
                }
            }
            for (i in 0 until height / 2) {
                vPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width / 2)
                offset += width / 2
                if (i < height / 2 - 1) {
                    vPlane.position(vPlane.position() + chromaRowPadding)
                }
            }
        }

        val yuvMat = Mat(height + height / 2, width, CvType.CV_8UC1)
        yuvMat.put(0, 0, yuvBytes)
        Imgproc.cvtColor(yuvMat, rgbaMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420, 4)
    }
}

return rgbaMat
}
```

And call it this way:

```
image.image?.let {
  if (it.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
      && it.planes.size == 3
  ) {
      val rgbaMat = it.yuvToRgba()
  }
}
```